# ASM int 0x10 stops working after jumping to second sector

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, bootloader

I'm trying to learn about how operating systems work, and so I'm working with making some basic code to run on the bootsector of an emulated floppy drive.  When I run the code, the code stored in the first sector of the floppy executes as expected; it prints the string:"Loading floppy", but then when it loads the next section of code it doesn't print the string "Sector 2 loaded", it just flails the cursor about(which is expected behavior).  I'm using Oracle VirtualBox to emulate a system with a floppy drive, and a hex editor to combine my binary files into a single .img file, compiled by NASM.  The code is excessively commented and inefficient for the purpose of making each bit of code clear in what it does.
Here's the code

---

Boot Sector (0x0000-0x01FF):

```
org 0x7C00      ;Tell compiler that this is where code starts
bits 16         ;The CPU is in Real 16bit mode

jmp Start       ;Skip over the string stored at the top of the program

Msg:    db "Loading the floppy ... "
EndMsg:

Start:
    mov bl, 0x0F    ;Set text colour to 15
    mov bh, 0x00    ;Set page to 0
    mov cx, 0x001   ;Set number of characters to 1
    xor dx, dx      ;Set x and y to 0
    mov ds, dx      ;Allow for message loading
    cld             ;Allow for message loading

Print:
    mov si, Msg     ;Load the pointer Msg into si

Char:
    mov ah, 0x02    ;Set the sub-function to 2
    int 0x10        ;Call function 0x10 - position cursor
    lodsb           ;load the byte at si into al

    mov ah, 0x09    ;Set the sub-function to 9
    int 0x10        ;Call function 0x10 - print character

    inc dl          ;Advance the cursor

    cmp dl, 80      ;If the cursor is past column 80
    jne Skip        ;Else jump to Skip
    xor dl,dl       ;reset the cursor's x value
    inc dh          ;move the cursor down a row

    cmp dh, 25      ;If the cursor is past line 25
    jne Skip        ;Else jump to Skip
    xor dh,dh       ;move the cursor to the top row

Skip:
    cmp si, EndMsg  ;If the message is finished
    jne Char        ;Else print another character

ResetDisk:
    mov ah, 0x00    ;Reset sub-function
    mov dl, 0x00    ;Drive declaration
    int 0x13        ;Disk function, sub 0 - Reset disk
    jc ResetDisk    ;If this fails, try again

ReadDisk:
    mov bx, 0x8000  ;Where in RAM to drop the read data
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, 0x0000  ;RAM offset value

    mov ah, 0x02    ;Set sub-function
    mov al, 0x01    ;Set the number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0x00    ;Set the cylinder to read
    mov cl, 0x02    ;Set the sector to start at (begins at 1, rest start at 0)
    mov dh, 0x00    ;Set the drive head to read from
    mov dl, 0x00    ;Set which drive to read from
    int 0x13        ;Disk function, sub 2 - Read disk as described above
    jc ReadDisk

AdvanceToSectorTwo:
    jmp 0x8000:0x0000                   ;Jump to the location of the second sector

    times 0x0200 - 2 - ($ - $$) db 0    ;Fill the rest of the first sector up to byte 510
    dw 0xAA55                           ;Set bytes 511 and 512 to be the boot-disk signature

    times 1474560 - ($ - $$) db 0       ;Fill up the rest of the floppy image as blank space
```

Sector-2(0x0200-0x3FF):

```
org 0x8000
bits 16

Start:
    mov bl, 0x0F    ;Set text colour to 15
    mov bh, 0x00    ;Set page to 0
    mov cx, 0x001   ;Set number of characters to 1
    mov dl, 23      ;Set column
    mov dh, 0       ;Set Row
    mov ds, dx      ;Allow for message loading
    cld             ;Allow for message loading

Print:
    mov si, Msg     ;Load the pointer Msg into si

Char:
    mov ah, 0x02    ;Set the sub-function to 2
    int 0x10        ;Call function 0x10 - position cursor
    lodsb           ;load the byte at si into al

    mov ah, 0x09    ;Set the sub-function to 9
    int 0x10        ;Call function 0x10 - print character

    inc dl          ;Advance the cursor

    cmp dl, 80      ;If the cursor is past column 80
    jne Skip        ;Else jump to Skip
    xor dl,dl       ;reset the cursor's x value
    inc dh          ;move the cursor down a row

    cmp dh, 25      ;If the cursor is past line 25
    jne Skip        ;Else jump to Skip
    xor dh,dh       ;move the cursor to the top row

Skip:
    cmp si, EndMsg  ;If the message is finished
    jne Char        ;Else print another character
    jmp Start       ;Restart this part of the program

Msg:    db "floppy sector 2 loaded!"
EndMsg:
```

---

Sorry that this is so long.  Again, It prints the first string just fine, but the second one it refuses to print, it just moves the cursor around.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, you load the code into **segment** `0x8000` but use `org 0x8000` which is segment `0x800`. Fix one or the other. Also, learn to use a debugger. PS: furthermore, you use `jmp 0x8000:0x0000` which uses an offset `0` anyway, so you really want `org 0`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the wrong value for ORG, as Jester points out in his comment, you also load DS with the value of 0023h, the initial value of your cursor. Instead you should load DS with the value stored in CS, that way your second sector doesn't care which segment it's loaded into. For example:

```
org 0
bits 16

Start:
    mov bl, 0x0F    ;Set text colour to 15
    mov bh, 0x00    ;Set page to 0
    mov cx, 0x001   ;Set number of characters to 1
    mov dl, 23      ;Set column
    mov dh, 0       ;Set Row
    push cs
    pop ds
    cld             ;Allow for message loading

...
```